# Domain wide Security Settings for Trusted Sites in IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Is it possible to create domain wide Security Settings for Trusted Sites in IE 7?

In other words, I want the same security settings for everyone in the domain for Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites > Custom Level...

Is this possible?  What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using Group Policy, I think it is in:  UserConf\AdmTempl\Windows Comp\Internet 
Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page - “Site to Zone Assignment 
List”?

This is for AD2003.

Another resource is here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569